# How can I improvement my code in blade with css colors?

Tags: laravel

I have in database table called `media` this table for users accounts on social media.

I need to say when in database twitter put the color of twitter like that: 
and with this code every thing is good but I need to make it shorter cuz. I have a lot of links so will be hard code if I always use **elseif**:

```
@forelse (auth()->user()->media as $media)

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <main class="social-media shadow-sm mb-3 d-flex" style="

            @if($media->name == 'Twitter')
                background-color: #1da1f2;
                color: #fff;
            @elseif($media->name == 'Facebook')
                background-color: #3b5999;
                color: #fff;
            @elseif($media->name == 'Codepen')
                background-color: red;
                color: #fff;
            @elseif($media->name == 'Behance')
                background-color: #131418;
                color: #fff;
            @endif

            ">

            <div class="media__icon">
                    {{ $media->name }}
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

@empty

@endforelse


this means get all media of user ( belongsToMany ) 
auth()->user()->media
```

the question how can I making my `if` code better than above one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css part

```
.background_Facebook{
  // Style here
}

background_Twitter{
  // Style here
}
```

Create a class background_Facebook, background_Twitter, etc
And call it like
Blade part
`class="background_{{$media->name}}"`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, interesting topic. First thing comes on my head (as Laravel way - not css class way) is create an accessor and return the desired colors from there (so you have single source of truth).

```
class Media extends Model {

    protected $twitter = [
        'background-color' => '#1da1f2',
        'color' => '#fff'
    ];

    public function css() {
        $colors = $this->(strtolower($this->name));

        $css = '';
        foreach ($colors as $key => $color) {
           $css .= "$key: $color;";
        }

        return $css;
    }
}
```

And then,

```
@forelse (auth()->user()->media as $media)

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <main class="social-media shadow-sm mb-3 d-flex" style="{{ $media->css }}">
           <div class="media__icon">
               {{ $media->name }}
           </div>
        </main>
    </div>

@empty

@endforelse
```

And ofcourse this is pseudo code and you should add some guards :)

Some guard can be:

```
$colors = $this->($this->name) ?? null;

if (!$colors) {
   // return dummy_colors or null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, depends on your needs :)